# VBA How to insert variables in to a body of an email

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am stuck with this problem, i have tried so many things but not working.
i want to send email with this macro, i can send emails but the email body is not including the variable values called "permit". I have list of permit on columnC, list of emails columnE and list of remainders on columnG. When i run this macro email is going perfectly but permits are not attaching with the body, i want to send every permit to the email following row. Any help?

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String

Cells(iCounter & "C").Select
Dim permit As String
permit = Cells(iCounter & "C").Value

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutLookMailItem
    MailDest = ""
        For iCounter = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(5))
            If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 5).Offset(0, 2) = "Send Reminder" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 5).Value
                ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 5).Offset(0, 2) = "Send Reminder" Then
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 5).Value
            End If
Next iCounter
    .BCC = MailDest
    .Subject = "Soon to Expire"


    .Body = "Reminder: Your Permit is about to expire Permit#" & permit
'here is the part where i want my permit variables to attach

    .Send
End With
Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
Set OutLookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The code it right, set a breakpoint right after `permit` gets set, and check its value. You could have the wrong worksheet active because you are not fully qualifying your Cell references.

Comment: in fact, you dont need `.Select` at all... just update this line... `permit = Cells(iCounter, "C").Value`

Comment: @braX, thank you very much for your help, i just tried that but it's showing another error. Runtime Error'287': Application-defined or object defined error and the bug refers to  `.Send` line. any idea?

Comment: This article talks about specifically that issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecce7b2a-8e4c-4e2e-b2e4-ad95f006d808/runtime-error-287-applicationdefined-or-objectdefined-error?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 0):

Use

`permit = Cells(iCounter, "C").Value`

or

`permit = Range("C" & iCounter).Value`

See the slight difference?

Comment: i just did that, and fixed the error. now it's not sending email at all.

Comment: That's a completely separate issue. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecce7b2a-8e4c-4e2e-b2e4-ad95f006d808/runtime-error-287-applicationdefined-or-objectdefined-error?forum=accessdev